# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''

Tags: php

I am getting a parse error when I run my script

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Program Files (x86).................\get.php on line 24

I cant see whats wrong, can someone help me with it?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
    } 
else 
    {
    $product1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE name=' . $product1 . ' ' ;

    $res = mysql_query($query) ;
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    {
    $result = mysql_fecth_assoc($res) ;
        echo json_encode($result['price']);
    }
    else
        {
        echo json_encode('no results') ;
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in your code, besides the missing quote in `$dbname = "database;`.

You're mixing MySQL APIs here. `mysql_` does NOT intermix with the `mysqli_` API.

- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

So, you need to change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and pass the connection parameter in the query.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Then, `mysql_fecth_assoc` was mispelled and corrected with the added `i`.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
    } 
else 
    {
    $product1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ;

    $query = 'SELECT price FROM forms WHERE name=' . $product1 . ' ' ;

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
        echo json_encode($result['price']);
    }
    else
        {
        echo json_encode('no results') ;
        }

    }
```

Check for errors also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$dbname = "database;
```

To

```
$dbname = "database";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` in this line:

```
$dbname = "database;
```

It should be:

```
$dbname = "database";
```

Hope this helps, thanks!